# Копирование в буфер обмена windows из google docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

сразу приношу свои извинения за этот глупый пост. Я долго изучал эту возможность и получил ответ, что это нельзя реализовать в JS без участия пользователя). Оно и понятно, что произошло бы если сайт получил бесконтрольный доступ к нашему буферу.
Но.. встречал информацию о каком-то флеш. Возможно ли его применить в google app script?

---

Задача:

1. Получить данные из [таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1benDuyOamJ3U2qPMsIHSQNp7T02Q4K1HhMbMabgKTZU/edit?usp=sharing) (**лист "copy"**) и изменить их
   *(доступ на редактирование закрыт, скопируйте файл на свой google drive чтобы посмотреть код)*
2. Скопировать в буфер

---

Мой код:

```js
function openModalDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('clipboardFileName')
      .evaluate()
      .setWidth(315)
      .setHeight(130),
      'Copy')
}

function getFileName() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('copy');
  let range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let name;
  if (col == "1") {
    name = sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue() + ".mxf"
  }
  return name
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>

  <textarea class="textarea_1" id="textarea1"></textarea>

  <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clipboard).getFileName()

    function clipboard(result) {
      let text = document.getElementById('textarea1')
      text.innerHTML = result;
      text.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _«встречал информацию о каком-то флеш. Возможно ли его применить в google app script?»_ - однозначно нет. Гугловский App Script никак не работает с покойным Flash (и не работал даже когда эта технология была жива).

Comment: И насколько помню, App Script это платформа выполнения кода **в облаке**, по принципу бессерверных функций - если помню верно, то такой код чисто технически не сможет получить доступ к браузеру (а значит, и к буферу обмена) кого-то-там-в-интернете... Для такого функционала, (по идее) браузерные расширения надо использовать... но и в них не все так просто.

Comment: @yar85 если google.script.run...  убрать в функцию и повесить ее на кнопку, то все работает:
  function startCopy(){
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clipboard).getFileName()}
  
 <button " onclick="startCopy()">script_run</button>

Comment: Стоп, так это аддон для Google Sheets? В аддонах да, к апишкам браузера может быть доступ - с теми же ограничениями, что и у обычных скриптов страниц (в данном случае, речь об ограничении доступа к буферу при отсутствии действия пользователя: копирование должно триггериться кликом по элементу, или нажатием клавиши, например).

Comment: @yar85 может есть какой-нибудь способ имитировать клик?

Comment: Есть, но действия политик безопасности браузера они не отменяют - программные клики из скриптов не расцениваются как действия пользователя. Обойти ограничение можно разве что написав бота который управляет браузером (или, соорудив механическое приспособление нажимающее кнопку мыши). Думаю, общий принцип ясен.

Comment: @yar85, все правильно. google.script.run - это Client-side API https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run. Аддоны, тут, правда, ни к чему. Это дополнительная возможность на стороне клиента, которая может реализовать Client-side API, как и Web Application (возможность на стороне клиента).

Comment: Документ поставляется во фрейме - дополнительная нагрузка на проверку безопасности. Если нужно железно записать в буфер, то только через пользователя https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: @contributorpw, спасибо за пояснение! А то что по ссылке, ТСу не поможет - ведь он хочет обойти политику безопасности (то есть, он уже научился копировать в буфер, и теперь хочет "обмануть" браузер, выполняя это в произвольный момент, без user gesture... что скриптом страницы никак не получится, конечно же: тут уж либо по событию интеракции копировать, либо писать "внешний" скрипт бота работающего через Puppeteer).

Comment: Хотя, если автора устроит однократная выдача permission'а, то `navigator.clipboard.writeText` может подойти. Только там нюанс - требование чтобы при вызове метода страница была активна (то есть: активное окно браузера, активная вкладка, фокус установлен на контенте страницы... и вот с последним, теоретически могут быть проблемки, если из ифрейма данный метод вызывать).

Comment: @yar85 во время копирования вкладка и так открыта, ведь перед этим нужно выбрать то, что нужно скопировать из таблицы. а в чем сложность выставить фокус на поле textarea ? focus() не поможет?

Comment: @yar85 сейчас проверил, focus() не работает. а если в момент загрузки кликать на модальное окно, то текст копируется.

Comment: @user1990, это игры с безопасностью. Сегодня работает - завтра нет. Дайте пользователю кнопку. Можно, конечно, попробовать `dispatchEvent`, но мне кажется, это все не от хорошего.

Comment: @user1990, если речь о методе `focus` поля ввода, то он не делает документ активным; если же речь об одноименном методе объекта `window`, то он стабильно разрешен только со "своими" программно открытыми вкладками в пределах хостнейма (в остальных случаях, возможна блокировка доступа к чужому объекту/ориджину - хотя именно с ифреймами, я не проверял). _«Дайте пользователю кнопку.»_ - на самом деле, это самое лучшее решение из возможных в данном случае.